# Upgrade from grails 2.5.4 to 3.1.8, GORM error

Tags: grails, grails-orm, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade project from grails 2.5.4 to 3.1.8 and now I am stuck on the following error.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.getSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:227)
org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:183)
org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:140)
org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:110)
org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.findWhere(AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:335)
org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.findWhere(GormStaticApi.groovy:658)
org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.findWhere(GormEntity.groovy:841)
org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$findWhere$4.call(Unknown Source)
com.etherapia.portal.security.User.findWhere(User.groovy)
com.etherapia.portal.security.User$findWhere$0.call(Unknown Source)
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService.$tt__loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:60)
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService$_loadUserByUsername_closure1.doCall(GormUserDetailsService.groovy)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy)
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:71)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie(TokenBasedRememberMeServices.java:123)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.autoLogin(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:75)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsSessionContext.currentSession(GrailsSessionContext.java:117)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
org.grails.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryProxy.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryProxy.java:148)
org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.getSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:225)
org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:183)
org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:140)
org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:110)
org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.findWhere(AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:335)
org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.findWhere(GormStaticApi.groovy:658)
org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.findWhere(GormEntity.groovy:841)
org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$findWhere$4.call(Unknown Source)
com.etherapia.portal.security.User.findWhere(User.groovy)
com.etherapia.portal.security.User$findWhere$0.call(Unknown Source)
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService.$tt__loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:60)
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService$_loadUserByUsername_closure1.doCall(GormUserDetailsService.groovy)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

The error shows up only in mozzila firefox, while chroome loads the page without assests. Images,css,js are not loaded properly in chroome.

Do you know where could be an issue?

Comment: the error resides here: com.etherapia.portal.security.User.findWhere(User.groovy)
com.etherapia.portal.security.User$findWhere$0.call(Unknown Source)
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService.$tt__loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:60)
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService$_loadUserByUsername_closure1.doCall(GormUserDetailsService.groovy)  the actual error is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread. Maybe you need to wrap it around @Transactional - not a lot to go on here I am afraid.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I face the same thing where there is no hibernate session when there should be

Comment: @Chris.D Yes, unfortunately I do not remember how. As far as I remember we rollbacked some changes I made during the upgrade. Then we did not encounter the error during the second attempt to upgrade, so we were happy, but I could have not resolved the issue. Since then I upgrade another project and I did not encountered this issue either. I am sorry, that I cannot help you more. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 3.1.1 of the spring security core plugin the method generating the exception is annotated as @Transactional (see below). Maybe you are using an older version?

```
class GormUserDetailsService implements GrailsUserDetailsService {

    protected Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass())

    /**
     * Some Spring Security classes (e.g. RoleHierarchyVoter) expect at least one role, so
     * we give a user with no granted roles this one which gets past that restriction but
     * doesn't grant anything.
     */
    static final GrantedAuthority NO_ROLE = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)

    /** Dependency injection for the application. */
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    @Transactional(readOnly=true, noRollbackFor=[IllegalArgumentException, UsernameNotFoundException])
    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        String userClassName = conf.userLookup.userDomainClassName
        def dc = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(userClassName)
        if (!dc) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The specified user domain class '$userClassName' is not a domain class")
        }

        Class<?> User = dc.clazz

        def user = User.findWhere((conf.userLookup.usernamePropertyName): username)
        if (!user) {
            log.warn 'User not found: {}', username
            throw new NoStackUsernameNotFoundException()
        }

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = loadAuthorities(user, username, loadRoles)
        createUserDetails user, authorities
    }
...
}
```